# Route for printer-formatted ERB view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Working with rails 3.1 here.

I'm wondering if there are any best practices for defining routes for views are meant to be sent to the printer. For instance, I have a report at "/daily" which has a print function that opens up a new nicely formatted printer view.

What URL should this view sit on? Couple ideas are:

- /daily/print
- /daily?media=print

What have other people used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine.

Probably the main consideration is whether your app is public facing and accessible to search engines.  Typically you want to prevent them from indexing (duplicate) content, which a printable version would be, and typically it's easier to exclude search engines (using the robots.txt file) from printable content if it's part of the path, as opposed to the query-string.

Otherwise, it's easier to just tack on the query string parameter and use that to set the printable version of your stylesheet and/or views.  This approach saves having to create a new route, which may be more flexible.